# What does "the trait bound std::fmt::Display is not satisfied" mean?

Tags: rust

My code:

```
extern crate time;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", time::get_time());
}
```

My error is:

`Error 'the trait bound time::Timespec: std::fmt::Display is not satisfied`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`println!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.println!.html) is a macro to do formatted output. `{}` is used to print a value that implements the [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait. The error is saying that `Timespec` does not implement the `Display` trait, so it cannot be used with `{}`.

You can use `{:?}` instead of `{}`. `{:?}` is used to print a value that implements [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) trait and `Timespec` implements it.

Consider reading the [`fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html) module documentation, it explain this in detail.

Comment: @ДмитрийКомар Also try reading the whole compiler error. It's not just noise, it's often actually useful: ```note: `time::Timespec` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string```